# Regular expression everything after a link

Tags: regex

I am a complete regular expression idiot, just keep that in mind :)

I am trying to create a regular expression that will match `link:xxxxxx` where everything after link: is a wildcard.

Can i just do `link:*` or am I totally misguided?

Comment: You can use `link:.*`

Comment: "I am a complete regular expression idiot, just keep that in mind :)" -> ideally you should then take a tutorial or read documentation on the subject rather than ask people. Not only will it help maintain the quality of stackoverfow (you can't judge the quality of your question if you don't know the topic) but it will be much more effective for you in the long term.

Comment: [A bit of reading material](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`link:.*` should work correctly. 
`.` matches any character, and you want to repeat it "0 to unlimited" times so you add `*`.

If you're new to regex, a good way to learn it is by using [regex101](https://regex101.com).

For your problem, you can check out this [regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/vZ8pM8/1)
(Note that I have also added the `g` modifier, which means that you want to select *all* matches, not just the first matching line)

Comment: Perfect! will take a look at regex101 thank you so much!